# Default value for Html dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 and c#. I have a `DropDownList` which I set using `ViewBag`.

```
  @Html.DropDownList("category_Parent", new SelectList(ViewBag.Category, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

By default it always selects the first value but I want it to select a null value (a default value). How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use the overload that accepts an option label. [Refer docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: @StephenMuecke:thank u